# Cannot use react-color Saturation with @types/react-color

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-color

I am trying to create a custom color picker using [react-color](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-color) library (^2.19.3) with [@types/react-color](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-color) (^3.0.4). As `Saturation` component is not exported from types [index](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-color/index.d.ts) file the only way to how to import it is `react-color/lib/components/common`. Using `Saturation` like ([this](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/50c3a0c032e614cd3cb8e581a6c057a4661c314d/types/react-color/react-color-tests.tsx#L28)):

```
<Saturation color={props.color} onChange={onChange} />
```

Will trigger an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'h' of undefined` (Types are not the same as original `Saturation` from [react-color](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-color) library).

I created minimal [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-bird-od39d?file=/src/App.tsx) (just uncomment `Saturation` section). Any Ideas on how to use `Saturation` component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what latest versions of both libraries are not compatible. After installation of `@types/react-color@2.17.5` problem disappeared with the usage of:

```
<Saturation hsl={props.hsl} hsv={props.hsv} ... />
```

Answer (score 2):

Passing `{...props}` will solve your problem where props has color, hsl, hex, hsv etc.

```
color: "orange"
hsl: Object
    h: 38.82352941176471
    s: 1
    l: 0.5
    a: 1
hex: "#ffa500"
    rgb: Object
    r: 255
    g: 165
    b: 0
    a: 1
hsv: Object
    h: 38.82352941176471
    s: 1
    v: 1
    a: 1
oldHue: 38.82352941176471
source: undefined
onChange: ƒ () {}
```

I read the [source](https://github.com/casesandberg/react-color/blob/master/src/components/common/Saturation.js), they need `hsl.h`, `hsl.v`, `hsl.s` to do the colouring. The hsl and hsv will be calculated by react-color based on the color and you just need to pass it to its component to use.

---

```
<Saturation
  {...props}
  onChange={(color: Color | ColorResult) => props.onChange?.(color)}
/>
```

Here is the codesandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-pond-vnsh6?file=/src/custom-theme-color-picker.tsx:865-875

Comment: This solution works however this is hacky.

Comment: I think hsl.h, hsl.v and hsl.s are must in the props so it is not hacky, even the official site pass the props in that way. I don't know why `@types/react-color@2.17.5` can work for you, it still shows error if i downgrade the version in codesandbox demo.

Comment: Interface for `Saturation` is different in `@types/react-color@3.0.4`

Comment: i see `@types/react-color@2.17.5` is using `hsv` as source, so you need to provide hsv instead of color but anyway if it works for you, then it is fine.

Comment: i see your edited answer, it is the same as {...props}, you just reassigning it explicitly . but anyway, if you feel comfortable with that way, it will be fine.